# Android Notification Channel silent ringtone by default

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-8.0-oreo, notification-channel

I want to create a Notification Channel for **Android Oreo** where the *default sound* is **silent**, I've tried to not specify the sound and it still plays a sound when the notification is dispatched. Any ideas?

```
NotificationChannel chan2 = new NotificationChannel(SECONDARY_CHANNEL,
            getString(R.string.noti_channel_second), 
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    chan2.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan2.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    getManager().createNotificationChannel(chan2);
```

Answer (score 1):

add `chan2.setSound(null, null);` when creating the channel.

Comment: In some device my app Force closes with this solution.. Not recommended